# React Native: Install to virtual/physical device failed

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm

I'm currently using React Native to code my final year project. I have an issue when build and install it to virtual/physical devices **althought a month ago it worked fine**. Can someone explain to me wwhat wrongs with my code or files? Does it get corrupted? Because I tried to created a blank new file I still get the same errors.

My error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
183 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 181 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\minht\SmartRoom\node_modules\react-native-image-crop-picker\android\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-14:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Comment: try to delete **build** folder in **android->app->build**  and run again.

Comment: I still got the same ```Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED``` error :(

Comment: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1406 refer this

Comment: After I change the build.gradles and re-installl all the node_modules, the problems changed to ```Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED``` and ```Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need upgrade Gradle from Android studio and then try if you can run your project from Android Studio.

Comment: I've tried to use the newest Gradle but still doesn't work tho xd...